# What is the smallest value of $x$ such that the matrix $A$ is not invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

> $$A = \begin{pmatrix}
> -1 & -3 & x \\
> -2 & -7 & -1 \\
> x & -6 & 1 
> \end{pmatrix}$$

So far I tried taking the determinant by expanding down the last column but i still cant get the right answer.

x * det $ \begin{pmatrix}
-2 & -7 \\x & -6 
\end{pmatrix} $ + 1 * det  $ \begin{pmatrix}
-1 & -3 \\
x & -6
\end{pmatrix} $ +1*det $ \begin{pmatrix}
-1 & -3 \\
-2 & -7 
\end{pmatrix} $

I end  up with $7x^2+15x+7$$=$$0$

Comment: That is the correct determinant. What is the smallest value of $x$ that solves that equation?

Comment: It's not nicely factorable, so you are going to have some square root in your answer.

Comment: Great, now use the quadratic formula to find where that polynomial equals 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right way continue by finding the roots

$x_1=-\frac{15}{14} - \frac{\sqrt{29}}{14}$

$x_2=-\frac{15}{14} + \frac{\sqrt{29}}{14}$

And taking the $\min\{x_1,x_2\} = -\frac{15}{14} - \frac{\sqrt{29}}{14}$

That's it that is your answer